Accidentally deleted a partition then Linux Mint is not working
I formatted a partition in Windows which has only 484mb and then I open Linux Mint(dual boot) it struck after Mint logo
It reads,
<Amd stoney kernal error....>
[ 12.900009] index 1 is out of range for type 'ATOM_PPLIB_Clock_Voltage_Depend

ency Record [1]

[12.915629)===========

You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "Journalcti -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.

Press Enter for maintenance

(or press Control-D to continue):
root@san:~#

When I press ctrl-D it shows,
exit

Reloading system manager configuration

Starting default target

Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).


How to get my Linux Mint back?

Instead of pressing Ctrl-D, can you check what's shown by systemctl --failed?

You can improve your post by advising what drives and partitions you have, and if Windows is installed as well. That said what you are trying to do is advanced, with many possible issues, and it is probably beyond the scope of a Q and A site to answer. Maybe find a local Linux Users Group?

Aldo, how did you delete your partition?

Can i get the system settings and installed program back?

In file explorer windows i formatted it

@grawity_u1686 i updated it can you check what's wrong now?

Use Boot Repair Tool
When we boot linux mint from live usb there is one program called boot repair just open it it will solve most of the boot related problems i guess but this above issue is solved for me hopefully
I got this solution in subreddit

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/s/8xNjTzAasK


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Quick fix: boot the linux mint CD into Live Mode. Run sudo apt update and then sudo apt install refind and agree to allow changes, then reboot. You should see an awesome picker to choose either Windows or Mint with a 30 second countdown. If not, you may also need to go into BIOS and tell it to use "REFIND" to boot from EFI partition.
Can you recall the drive letter you formatted and was it the one the machine came with or the 2nd? Also why did you format it? Did that work out apart from denial of access to linux? Can you still boot windows OK? Does this machine only have 1 drive?
In the old days, when disks were MBR format, the boot-block is always the first block on the disk: cylinder 0. If you fully killed your EFI but windows can still boot... then I guess you have 2 drives in this computer and one is format MBR? Not sure. Probably not. Probably you told windows to wipe the 484mb and re-install the Windows boot EFI folder.
I will assume Windows was installed first into a GPT style disk, and the partition layout is:
[CYLINDER-0][EFI-Fat32][WINDOWS-NTFS][LINUXMINT-Ext4]
My guess is that you formatted your drives EFI system partition inside Windows, such that Winodws is still able to boot; in this case a folder called Ubuntu or Mint was likely missing from the freshly formatted EFI partition (the 484MB one).
If you killed your EFI you may need to consider getting it back. Make it 800MB if you do. Then install refind into it.

This post would seem to only confuse things more (and indeed the problem is unclear enough without it).    For a start the issue would not be UEFI as the kernel has already loaded (so we are way past UEFI's involvement - indeed at this point even the contents of whatever would normally map to /boot have been found as there is a minimum Linux system running).

That drive letter is d.  I don't know about how that partition show up in windows i thought i was accidentally made that partition. Yess i can boot my windows. How to find which is mbr which is gpt?

@davidgo the problem is very unclear to me that why i came here i have tried almost every solution mentioned in other similar problems but nothing works im still at the same point...

@davidgo you don't think he wiped his EFI partition? It's 484mb.

@Tomachi I don't know what he wiped, but I do know a Linux kernel was loaded which strongly implies that either UEFI was not used or more likely that UEFI was in tact.
